# Ошибка в обработке исключения деления на 0

Tags: java

Хочу обработать деление на ноль, но ошибка в `try` и `catch`. Как исправить?

Создал свое исключение:

```
public class DivisionByZero extends Exception {

public DivisionByZero() {
    super("Деление на ноль!");
}

 }
```

И кнопку равно:

```
bt_res.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            double second_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
            if ("+".equals(operation[0])) {
                jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] + second_value) + "");
            }
            if ("-".equals(operation[0])) {
                jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] - second_value) + "");
            }
            if ("/".equals(operation[0])) {
                if (second_value == 0) {
                } catch (ArithmeticException e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Calculator.this, "Деление на ноль запрещено!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] / second_value) + "");
            }
            if ("*".equals(operation[0])) {
                jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] * second_value) + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: У вас со скобками напутано. try и catch должны находится на одном уровне вложенности

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться... Ошибочные арифметические операции бросают исключение ArithmeticException. Сделайте блок try - catch, внутри которого проводите все вычисления и  перехватывайте это исключение. Можно эти вычисления в отдельный метод вызвать, который бросает данное исключение. Все просто. Зачем вам нужен класс DivisionByZero - остается загадкой

Comment: Просто хочу, чтобы это было проверяемое исключение

Comment: А вот со скобками не получается разобраться.

Comment: А каким образом нужно сделать, чтобы try и catch находились на одном уровне вложенности?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

возможно лучше будет так (как писали выше) сделать - вынести реализацию в отдельный метод

```
void method() throws DivisionByZero {
    if ("+".equals(operation[0])) {
        jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] + second_value) + "");
    } else if ("-".equals(operation[0])) {
        jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] - second_value) + "");
    } else if ("/".equals(operation[0])) {
        if (second_value == 0) {
           throw new DivisionByZero();
        }
        jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] / second_value) + "");
    } else if ("*".equals(operation[0])) {
        jtextfield.setText((first_value[0] * second_value) + "");
    }
}
```

и обрабатывать вызов подобным образом

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        method();
    } catch (DivisionByZero e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть блок catch (ArithmeticException e1) не нужен?

Comment: да, верно, он не нужен, т.к. есть проверка значения на 0, которая будет выдавать соответствующее сообщение

Comment: Ну тогда ни какого исключения не будет, этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Может это возможно как то по другому сделать?

Comment: см. выше - я обновил пост с решением